# Можно ли средствами css нарисовать стрелку, отличную от простых &larr; и &rarr;?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли как-то такому элементу, как стрелка, предать другую форму, ширину, высоту и т.д.? Через css или java. Заказчику нужна стрелка так, как на его картинке, вот такого вида:

[image: https://gyazo.com/375ab4eca8f3f58a2e6101cab0c305f5]

Через картинку это делать не хочется, потому что много геммора и полетит вся вёрстка, да и для стрелки использовать целую картинку как-то нерационально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте для стрелочки шрифт Calibri. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/txxLtxmx/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

При замене шрифта обрати внимание, что его может не быть у посетителя.
Также обрати внимание на различное отображение шрифтов в разных браузерах и на различных устройствах.